Neural Network Overfitting on Linearly Separable Dataset
Please let me know if this question is not proper to ask here
For context, I have a dataset regarding to tiktok user engagement. The predicted variable is binary, either 'claim' or 'opinion'. From histograms of numeric data, and scatter plots of each pair of them below, it looks the dataset could be almost linearly separable. Note: numeric data are in log scale


I applied MLPClassifier to model neural networks to classify this dataset but all seems to overfit siginificantly, even setting only 1 node (by hidden_layer_size to (1,)). Everything else was left default. So far I tried increase regularization term alpha, decrease batch_sizes, use lbfgs as solver, but all couldn't fix the issue. Is there still anything to do to fix the issue or Neural Network simply doesn't fit this problem? I definitely can switch to use other models like random forest but just wonder the reason for learning purposes. I can provide more details if needed.

